# Factorial program c using recursive function in C with while loop

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

Factorial program using recursion in c with while loop.In this program once the execution reaches the function return statement it will not go back to the function call. Instead,it executes the function repeatedly. can anybody please tell me what's wrong in this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int fact(int n)
{    
    int x=1;    

    while(n>1)    
    {    
        x=n*fact(n-1);    
    }    

    return(x);    
}    

void main()    
{    
    int n,fact1;    
    scanf("%d",&n);    
    fact1=fact(n);    
    printf("%d",fact1);    
}
```

Comment: Does changing the while to an if solve the problem?

Comment: Your program has an infinite loop when `n > 1`, see Peter's comment

Comment: BTW, if this is a homework problem, please tag it with [tag:homework].

Comment: Just thought you might appreciate some input. Your approach to the problem (implementing factorial recursively?) is wrong. There are two ways to implement factorial, and it seems like you're combining them -- rethink how it works.

Answer (score 6):

The reason that your program gets into an infinite loop is that the loop

```
while (n > 1)
    x = n * fact(n-1);
```

never decrements `n`.  Since `n` never decreases, the program will never leave the loop.  Peter is correct in the comments: change the `while` to an `if`, and you will have a factorial function that handles all positive parameters correctly.  However, even after changing `while` to `if`, your `fact` won't have the property that `fact(0) == 1`, as is required for a correct factorial function.

Answer (score 5):

This

```
while(n>1)
```

is causing the looping. You don't change `n` inside the loop, so the loop is infinite.

Change `while` to `if`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the method of factorial:

```
public int fact(int n)
    {
        if (n < 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return n * fact(n - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** main returns int, use it! */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

if (argc <= 2) {
        if (argv) argc = atoi(argv[1] );
        else return argc;
        }

argc *= main (argc-1, NULL);

if (argv) {
        printf("=%d\n", argc);
        return 0;
        }
return argc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
Write a C++ Program to input a positive number,
Calculate and display factorial of this number
by recursion.
*/
#include<iostream.h>

#include<conio.h>

long  factorial(int n);
void main()
{

  clrscr();

  int number, counter;


  label1:

  cout<<"\n Enter the Number = ";

  cin>>number;

  if ( number < 0)
  {
  cout<<"\n Enter a non negative number, please!";
  goto label1;
  }
  cout<<"\n\n ----------- Results ------------";

  cout<<"\n\n The Factorial of the number "<<number<<"\n is "<<factorial(number);

  getch();

}

long factorial(int n)

{

    if ( n == 0 )
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n-1);

}
```

Comment: OP asked for C, not c++

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple approach using recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n-1);
}
int main()
{
    int f;
    f = fact(5);
    printf("Factorial = %d",f);
    return 0;
}
```

Read it more [C program to find factorial using recursion](http://codeforwin.org/2016/02/c-program-to-find-factorial-of-number-using-recursive-function.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
/*several versions of a factorial program.*/

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
  {
  int n;
  long factorial;
  printf("Compute the factorial of what number? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  factorial = 1L;
  while(n > 0)
    factorial *= n--;
  printf("The factorial is %ld\n", factorial);
  return 0;
  }

 #include<stdio.h>
/*the same, but counting up to n instead of down to 0*/
int main()
  {
  register int count;
  int n;
  long factorial;
  printf("Compute the factorial of what number? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  factorial = 1L;
  count = 1;
  while(count <= n)
    factorial *= count++;
  printf("%d! = %ld\n", n, factorial);
  return 0;
  }


 #include<stdio.h>
/*an equivalent loop using 'for' instead of 'while'*/
int main()
  {
  register int count;
  int n;
  long factorial;
  printf("Compute the factorial of what number? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for(factorial = 1L, count = 1; count <= n; count++)
    factorial *= count;
  printf("%d! = %ld\n", n, factorial);
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*WAP to find factorial using recursion*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int fact1=1;

int fact(int no)
{
    fact1=fact1*no;
    no--;
    if(no!=1)
    {
        fact(no);
    }
    return fact1;
}

int main()
{
    int no,ans;``
    system("clear");
    printf("Enter a no. : ");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    ans=fact(no);
    printf("Fact : %d",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Factorial program using recursion in C with while loop.

```
int fact(int n)
{    
    int x=1;    

    while(n>=1)    
    {    
        return(n*fact(n-1));    
    }    

    return(1);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach.

```
int factorial(int a)
{
    while(a>1)
    {
        return a*factorial(a-1);
    }
    return 1;


}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. 
This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.